# SqlPlus script to update data and log the update values in a CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, plsql, sqlplus

I am creating a shell script which uses sqlplus to update data in an Oracle database.

I have a **user** table like This.

| id_user | name | statut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 1 |
| 2 | bbb | 1 |

and another table **user_log** like this.

| date | nb_rows_affected | details |
| --- | --- | --- |

the log table contains the column details which is a CLOB where I would like to log in details all updates that have been made in the user table.

I'll give you an example, let's say we have the above information in the user table, and we want to update the name and the status of the user aaa to user.name == ccc and his statut to user.statut=2
so I will do it like this

```
update user set statut = 2 and name = 'ccc' where id_user = 1
```

I want that automatically after the update we have the following information in the table of log

```
date = current_date 
nbrow_affected = 1 
details : new values (statut = 2 and name = 'ccc') old values (statut = 1 and name = 'aaa') for id_user= 1
```

I've been searching it the only way to do it is with triggers on user table update because it can use the new.name and old.name statement, but I'm stuck on how to implement it properly

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a trigger which interrogates each column. Its verbose but you could also write a routine to generate this for you automatically out of USER_TAB_COLUMNS

The trigger code will be along the lines of:

```
declare
  c clob;
begin
  if updating(col1) then c := c || 'old='||:old.col1||',new='||:new.col1; end if;
  if updating(col2) then c := c || 'old='||:old.col2||',new='||:new.col2; end if;
  if updating(col3) then c := c || 'old='||:old.col3||',new='||:new.col3; end if;
  if updating(col4) then c := c || 'old='||:old.col4||',new='||:new.col4; end if;
  ...
  ...
end;
```

And at the end of that, you'll store the clob 'c' in your logging table